# Delete Last Record per Group (ID) in R

Tags: r

Here is my data:

```
> PayInstance   EMPLID   DEPTID JOBCODE PAY_FREQUENCY MAX._TTL.GROSS
> 1 1 23231606  100880             W           1203
> 2 1 23231606  100880             W            597
> 3 1 23231606  100880             W            625
> 4 1 23231606  100880             W            245
> 5 1 23231606  100880             W            480
> 6 1 23231606  100880             W            758
> 7 1 23231606  100880             W            599
> 1 2 23231606  100880             W            551
> 2 2 23231606  100880             W            767
> 3 2 23231606  100880             W            880
> 3 2 23231606  100880             W            557
> 4 2 20441606  100880             W            909
```

Here is what I would like to do:

```
> PayInstance   EMPLID   DEPTID JOBCODE PAY_FREQUENCY MAX._TTL.GROSS
> 1 1 23231606  100880             W           1203
> 2 1 23231606  100880             W            597
> 3 1 23231606  100880             W            625
> 4 1 23231606  100880             W            245
> 5 1 23231606  100880             W            480
> 6 1 23231606  100880             W            758
> 1 2 23231606  100880             W            551
> 2 2 23231606  100880             W            767
> 3 2 23231606  100880             W            880
> 3 2 23231606  100880             W            557
```

This is my start, but I'm assuming I'll need to write my own function for this, hope someone can be helpful as I'm sure I am not

```
df %>%
  group_by(EMPLID) %>%
```

Comment: ... `%>% slice(-n())`

Comment: In base R, you could do `dat[ave(dat$EMPLID > 0, dat$EMPLID, FUN=function(x) c(head(x, -1), FALSE)), ]`.

Comment: First, thanks for the responses. When I use the base r dat[ave(dat$EMPLID > 0, dat$EMPLID, FUN=function(x) c(head(x, -1), FALSE)), ] is there a way to make it only apply to a specific group? For example, if I only want it to apply to a group 1 that is coded 0 or 1. Where could that need to go?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the perfectly valid answers in the comments here are alternative solutions using `dplyr` and `data.table`

```
## Data table
setDT(df)
df[, obs := 1:.N]
df[df[, max(obs) != obs, by = EMPLID]$V1, ]


## Dplyr
df$obs <- 1:nrow(df)
df %>% group_by(EMPLID) %>% filter(max(obs) != obs)
```